# frezzing ui app when set adapter to RecyclerView or when notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: java, android, adapter

i have list with 30 items . when i set  adapter to  RecyclerView
or when notifyDataSetChanged method called , the ui of app  will 
 frezzing for a few seconds.

here my code
adapater and set :

```
      public AdapterBarberWorkTimeDetails(List<BarberWorkPeriodItems> items, int itemLayout, Context context, String date, FragmentReserveBarberWorkTime parentFragment) {
        this.items = items;
        this.itemLayout = itemLayout;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.date = date;
        this.parentFragment = parentFragment;
        }

 public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
```

View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(itemLayout, parent, false);
         return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

```
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AdapterBarberWorkTimeDetails.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

  holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                             // do some thing
                              }
               // set text to items
  }

//the viewholder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
          // finde items
        }
    }

}

---- 
// the mothod  call adaptet and set it to RecyclerView

 public void generateSpecialDaysDetails(List<BarberWorkPeriodItems> workPeriods, String date) {
        adapterBarberWorkTimeDetails = new AdapterBarberWorkTimeDetails(workPeriods, R.layout.adapter_barber_work_periods, getActivity(), date, this);
        rvWorkPeriod.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvWorkPeriod.setAdapter(adapterBarberWorkTimeDetails);
        linearLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 4, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        rvWorkPeriod.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    }
```

// my xml

```
//item view for adapter;
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHours"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="00:00"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
// the RecyclerView
      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:id="@+id/rvWorkPeriod"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="300dp"
                                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                                android:minHeight="100dp"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

what is the problem??

Comment: post the code where you are calling this adapter.Also post entire adapter code to understand it better.

Comment: What does `ApplicationLoader.detectTimeStatus` do?

Comment: @haresh   edit  my question for you

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman get color for some status

Comment: This is most likely a view related issue. Post your recycler view and it's items XML code.

Comment: @Sdghasemi I posted xml now

Comment: @androidLover and your recycler items xml?

Comment: @Sdghasemi  part 1  is recycler items xml that i commented  this :  item view for adapter;